# Every time I eneble secure boot for windows 11 my pc doesnt boot and I have to reset bios settings by removing battary. Why is that?

Tags: boot, security, bios, secure-boot, windows-11

So basically I want to update to windows 11 and I have to eneble 2 security settings TPM and secure boot I succesfully enebled Tpm but each time I try to do the same with secure boot my screen, keyboard,mouse are not working.I have tried every way to eneble it but I have the same result each time. What should I do

Motherboard:Gigabyte B450M DS3H

Bios model:f50

Comment: Did you install Windows 10 with CPM enabled or disabled?  Secure Boot is only compatible if BIOS mode is set to UEFI.  You can check that within System Information.

Comment: Bios mode isnt set with UEFI. So I will have to re-instal .Where will I find the option which says to download UEFI though?

Comment: Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 installation asks to convert to UEFI.  I suggest you try that.

Comment: @John160 - **Don’t reinstall.**  Use MBR2GPT provided your partition layout meets the requirements to do so, then simply disable CSM (or whatever it’s called on your system) and enable Secure Boot.  If you reinstall you are choosing to do something totally unnecessary

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks guys problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 is not out yet.  Enter a case with Windows Insider Windows 11 forum.  (Feedback Hub).

Update the computer BIOS to see if that works.

You need UEFI and Secure Boot both to run Windows 11.

Follow up:  You need to be using UEFI (which is now very common and I assumed this) and so when you re-install as you say you will, let the Windows 10 installation convert to UEFI.

Then contact the computer manufacturer's support line to see if they have a fix for Windows 11.

It may be your computer is not Windows 11 - compliant.

Comment: By the way, John is referring to the Feedback Hub, it's basically inaccessible outside of the Feedback Hub application